# What happened to testthat?

Tags: r, unit-testing, automated-tests

I don't remember having any problems with this, but seemingly suddenly, I can't install any packages because `testthat` is not there to pass tests. As a catch-22, I can't install `testthat` either, because it's not there to pass its tests.

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Error in library(testthat) : there is no package called 'testthat'
[Previously saved workspace restored]

> 
> install.packages("testthat")
Installing package into '/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
trying URL 'http://cran.cs.wwu.edu/src/contrib/testthat_0.8.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 40777 bytes (39 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 39 Kb

Error in library(testthat) : there is no package called 'testthat'
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> library
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpMoaIPO/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("testthat") :
  installation of package 'testthat' had non-zero exit status
```

Is there a way to bypass testing for one install run or otherwise work around this so I can fix my R install?

Comment: Have you tried updating to `Spring Dance` ? (R 3.1.0)

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Is `testthat` now a required part of a base install?

Comment: no, it [isn't part of r-base](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html); presumably it wasn't available on CRAN for a little while (maybe only a given mirror+platform combination).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I live somewhere with poor internet, and I didn't want to download a new version of R and all its dependencies to fix this problem. So you can install an old version of testthat manually:
http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/testthat/

On version 3.0.2, testthat version 0.8.1 seems to work. Once you have downloaded the gzip file, do:

`R CMD INSTALL testthat_0.8.1.tar.gz`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using linux, you don't have to manually download the package, installing the dependency( in this case 'testthat') via your default manager will also work. I have ubuntu 14.04 and R 3.0.2

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-testthat
```

After running the above command I was able to finally install swirl.

Comment: Caveat: Ubuntu has a reputation for being behind on CRAN and CTAN updates, to name a few.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander true, thanks for pointing that out. I just checked Ubuntu trusty's(14.04) r packages and the latest packages is for R 3.0.2 I guess the safest bet is to add the r-cran mirrors to the source list. I am also, figuring out things, trying to set up R myself.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a full update fixed this, but I don't know why.